# Order of the subgroups of an infinite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Take the infinite abelian subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, $N=\left\{\textstyle\begin{pmatrix}\lambda &0\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}:\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+\right\}$. Do all subgroups of $N$ also have infinite order?

If so why? And how can I show that?

Comment: Other than the trivial subgroup, they all have infinite order. $N$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R^+,\times)$. Is there any element of that group which is finite order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true. For example {I} is a definite subgroup of N. If it is about proper subgroups It's true. You can prove in diffrent ways. One way: Proof by contradiction                  Assume that there is a proper subgroup which has definite order. Beacuse it is proper subgroup, it has a member which is not equal to identity. While productions of this member is shown as lambda to n, you have to show for all integers for n, these powers of lambda are not equal So infinite members are creating by producting  .